# Excel Drop Down with IF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to create a sheet that uses drop downs and fills in some blank spaces based on selection.

Let's say the drop down has Apple, Banana, Cucumber, and Pear. When I create the tables for each one, I have additional information for each one. A1 is the finding word (vlookup) and the other 3 in this case are additional pieces of information.

Sheet(Data)

A1: Apple
A2: Made in USA
A3: Red
A4: Round

On Sheet1, I have a drop down. When I choose Apple on A20, I'd like to fill in A21, A22, A23 with the descriptions as above. So when choosing Apple, it fills it in. If I chose Banana, it could have different variables with it depending on what I put under Banana.

I'm familiar with IF statement, but it seems like it would be too many variables. I have 15 "fruits" to choose from and each one may contain something different to fill in those spaces.

Would this be a possibility?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you're asking. Vlookup is probably the simplest.

First, you need a table somewhere which has all of your data in it. Something that has all of your fruits in one column, and then a column for each attribute (location, colour, etc.) to the right.

So on sheet2, you could put your raw table data. Starting at A1, you type your fruits on column A, etc.

Then your formula on sheet 1 would look at what you've typed in cell A1, and pull data from sheet 2, based on that value. For example, sheet1 A2, which looks for the fruit's location, would be:

```
=vlookup(A1,sheet2!A1:D5,2)
```

Assuming your table on sheet2 starts at A1 with fruits on column A, and location in column B, and it goes only to row 5.

Comment: Given the orientation of the example, I was thinking that the [HLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-f3f3b210-5dd6-4b58-9c83-b9db2c306d6a) would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Jeeped is right - my comments above only apply if you have your "index key" (the type of fruit, in this case) running along a column. If instead your fruits are along the top, so row 1 shows fruit, row 2 shows location, etc., then the formula would be =hlookup(A1,sheet2!A1:E4,2)

Comment: Thank you both! I got it to work using the extra tips. Luckily, I didn't have the data filled in yet so I was able to do it the VLookup way but I just learned a new function so thanks @Jeeped. I really need to learn VLOOKUP!! Thank you a million more times!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) to help correlate between two lists.