# Get text from drop down list cell

Tags: string, excel

I have a list of options, a single column of data.

I defined a name for them, mylist, and so I have a list.

In a form on other sheet, I want the user to select from the options in that list. So I went to data>data validation>data validation>settings>allow>list mylist.

But I want some stuff to happen depending on what the user selected.

For example, if mylist were colors:

```
red
blue
orange
grey
```

Let's say the user selects blue from the list.

In another cell I want just the first letter of the selected color to appear.

so I tried

```
=LEFT(A1,1)
```

where A1 is a cell with the list of options as a drop down menu.

But then it shows an error saying the cell has restricted input...

Is there any way to get this info?

Comment: Are you putting the formula in the same cell as the drop down?

Comment: Consider this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31299191/5090027 as well as any number of questions on conditional formatting.

Comment: The cell in which you put this formula must also have a data validation.  Remove the validation and the formula should work.